# Creating a painterly effect using Geo Nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry

In short, I want to give a painterly look to my objects. A pretty big issue I've been hit with so far is how to assign the instanced objects to essentially show the material of the object they're on top of. In this example, I have a cube with a wood texture on most sides, and a brick on one side. I'd like the paint stroke plane on the left side to essentially copy the material of the cube. Pic 3 is an paintover of what I'd want to achieve in Blender.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: AFAIK GN can't access shader information, but it CAN access UV map information. The tricky part is how to transfer that to the instances and make them aware of their surroundings. Obviously in a simple cube setup, using Generated coordinates would simply remove the need for UV mapping

Comment: @Gorgious object based coordinates would be even easier and potentially flexible.

Comment: You could try using a data transfer modifier after the geo nodes to transfer the UVs back

Comment: Check out Stylized Station.
Some links: https://youtu.be/RhW5MwCSjKw https://youtu.be/h8llGEKIQT0 https://youtu.be/rXdeJ_sigf4

Comment: Wouldn't instancing simple planes on it and then adding a linear blur and a factor texture for the brushy alpha texture solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this.
making a geometry node projecting brush meshes onto a box and then adding a material that separates the xyz textures.
you can download the blend file here and add your own images textures into it:
https://we.tl/t-egvm1do3L0

[image]

[image]